# I need to load an excel file into python 2.7 using an interface

Tags: python, excel, interface

in order to do some operations with it but I would like to do it from an interface in order to select the file instead of just running a script with the name of the file, as the file name will change every day.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is simply not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tkinter `askopenfilename` :

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

path = askopenfilename()

f = open(path, 'r') # OR DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH PATH
```